# Using variables in left join

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT
  o.id            AS id,
  o.price_decimal AS price_decimal,
  p.sum_with_tax  AS sum_withtax,
  @price_decimal := price_decimal
FROM orders o
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT order_id,quantity,tax_rate,price,
                ROUND(SUM((price * (tax_rate / 100 + 1) * quantity)), @price_decimal) AS sum_with_tax,
                sum(quantity * price)                                                 AS sum,
                sum(quantity)                                                         AS sum_quantity
              FROM orders_positions
              GROUP BY order_id) p
    ON o.id = p.order_id
```

I need the **@price_decimal** variable. The content of this field is defined in the table orders.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: maybe `SELECT @price_decimal` will do?

Comment: the returned value "sum_withtax" is NULL. is the syntax basically correct?

Comment: You don't need the variable at all. Your subquery can "see" the outer table. Instead of `@price_decimal`, simply use `o.price_decimal`.

Comment: that was my first try. the error message calls "Unknown column 'o.price_decimal' in field list".

Answer (score 1):

Please try it:

```
SELECT 
    o.id AS id, o.price_decimal AS price_decimal, p.sum_with_tax AS sum_withtax,
p.order_id,  p.quantity,     p.tax_rate,     p.price,
      ROUND(SUM((p.price * (p.tax_rate / 100 + 1) * p.quantity)), o.price_decimal) AS sum_with_tax,
            sum(p.quantity * price) AS sum,
            sum(p.quantity) AS sum_quantity
FROM  orders o
inner join orders_positions p ON o.id = p.order_id
group by p.order_id
```